# Georeferenced vector file to raster file problem

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, georeferencing, rasterization

When I rasterize the vector file it keeps getting an error 6. How do I manually put a -3d,-a, or -burn value? 
I am only a beginner.
Feel free to ask for clarifications about my problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). All questions should always include a complete description of the software environment, and the exact syntax of the commands which have been used, ***and*** the *exact* error message, in its entirety, as ASCII, in the question body. A screenshot is optional, but often useful.